# convert <class 'list'> to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, openai-gym

I am a bit new to python and I am working with miniWOB from OpenAI. I want to print out with cv2 what my observations are for my agent. But really doesn matter. My problem is I do not know exact which data type I receive from the gym for my "observation". But I want it as a simple 3Dimensional numpy array. This format I can print out using cv2. So can anybody help me to convert my < class 'list> observation to: < type nunpy.ndarray>? I already tried observation = np.asarray(observation) but then I got this error: "mat data type = 17".

```
import cv2
import random
import gym
import universe
import go_vncdriver
import numpy as np
def main():
   env = gym.make('wob.mini.ClickTest-v0')
   env.configure(remotes=1)  # create one flashgames Docker container
   observation = env.reset()
   while True:
       env.render()
       x = 110
       y = 270

        action_n = [universe.spaces.PointerEvent(x, y, 1), universe.spaces.PointerEvent(x, y, 0),
            universe.spaces.PointerEvent(x, y, 1)]

         action_n = [action_n for ob in observation]
         observation, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)

         observation = np.asarray(observation) #this one converts to nd array but then I got the mat data type = 17 error
         if (observation != None):
            print(type(observation))
            cv2.imshow('pong voor net', observation)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
main()
```

I receive this:

```
    [{'vision': array([[[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   ..., 
   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8), 'text': []}]
```

I want to convert it to this type:

```
[[[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
..., 
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]]

[[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
..., 
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]]

[[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
..., 
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]
[144  72  17]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely familiar with world of bits, but based on the output, I would assume that you have an array of observationS (in your case just one) and each observation consists of a dict, probably you could have other sensor input as well, but in your example it just contains the visible observation 'vision' (i.e. the pixels). So to get the array you want you select the first element and extract the "vision" element:

```
observation = np.asarray(observation[0]['vision'])
```